# Android Studio convert java module to android module

Tags: java, android

In my Android project i have a few modules. Some of them is android module and some java module. 
Now i want to convert java module to android module. 
Is Android studio has standard way for this?

Answer (score 6):

A Java module uses `apply plugin: 'java'` in its build.gradle, whereas an Android module uses `apply plugin: 'com.android.library'`.

Change this in your Java module, along with compileSdkVersion, buildToolsVersion, defaultConfig, and buildTypes.

With all these changes your build.gradle file will look like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar', '*.aar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.1.0'

}
```

Comment: Now i have error Error:Cannot read packageName from /xxx/yyy//src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: In case of Error:Cannot read packageName from /xxx/yyy//src/main/AndroidManifest.xml
Just create AndroidManifest.xml under your-module/src/main/ with the very simple content: 
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.yourpackagename" />
Then sync project.

Comment: Mine says `plugins {
 id 'com.android.library'
}` but still shows up as a 'Java module' when I mouse over the project folder in Android Studio.